# lxml.etree iterparse does not accept a HDFS file path

Tags: python, pyspark, hdfs, amazon-emr, iterparse

I would like to process a huge xml file that is distributed across a HDFS file system, using the `iterparse` function from `lxml.etree` package.

I have tried it locally and on an Amazon's EMR cluster:

- **Locally** : the address of my xml file is `hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/history.xml`
- **EMR cluster** : the address is `/user/hadoop/history.xml`

In both cases, running my simple python program crashes with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xml_parser.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "xml_parser.py", line 12, in main
    for event, elem in ET.iterparse(inputFile, tag='page'):
  File "src/lxml/iterparse.pxi", line 78, in lxml.etree.iterparse.__init__
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: <file_path>
```

Here is my python program

```
import sys
import lxml.etree as ET
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession



def main():
    sc = SparkContext()
    spark = SparkSession(sc)
    inputFile = sys.argv[1]
    for event, elem in ET.iterparse(inputFile, tag='page'):
        elem.clear()
    print('finished')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What if you just open the file yourself and pass the open file object to `iterparse`?

Comment: I tried this. But, iterparse accepts only a file path, not a file content

Comment: That doesn't appear to be true. I was able to pass a file object to `iterparse` with no errors. Note that you need to open the file in binary mode (`open("somefile.html", "rb")`).

Comment: My bad. I did not think of this, passing a file object to iterparse. Indeed, we can use a file object instead of a file path. Thank you :)